# Take a word from a special place in the string

Tags: batch-file, cmd

The thing i need help is if the user types the string: `commandLine("Dir")`
then it will take the Dir from `commandLine("Dir")` and make it to a variable

Example:

```
C:\> program.bat commandLine("Dir")

program.bat:

echo the command is: Dir

pause
```

Comment: Why would the user type commandLine("Dir") instead of just Dir?

Comment: I am making a new cmd in batch that will have it's own commands so the only way to get the cmd commands is to type commandLine("Dir") and yeah it is weird but i like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo off
set str=%1
set str=%str:CommandLine("=%
set str=%str:")=%
echo on
echo the command is: %str%
```